# Setting the country and language when redirecting to login page of paypal

Tags: paypal

After having aquired a token via express checkout I redirect the user to paypal using this tag:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="1; url=https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&lc=FR&country=FR&token=EC-sometoken"></meta>
```

Even if I set country=FR and lc=FR I always get the login page displayed in german language and with german payment methods.

Is there another way to set language and country?

Apart from that the payment works and I can select a different country (not language) on the loginpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I turned out that I had to set the attribute LocaleCode in SetExpressCheckoutRequestType when I request the token.